# how can a client have a several connections through one server in paralel?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm doing a project that is suposed to be a chat: one server and a few clients that talk with each other in parallel through the server. The problem is that one client can't have more then one conversation, because then the server won't be able to know which message belongs to which conversation.

server code:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)
# logging.debug

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 555


class Server():

def __init__(self, host, port):  # listening...
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.clients = 0
    self.clients_dict = {}
    self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
    self.sock.listen(100)
    print 'listening...'

def search_for_connections(self):  # connection with several clients in parallel
    while self.clients < 100:
        connection, address = self.sock.accept()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.first_stage, args=(connection, address,))
        t.start()

def first_stage(self, connection, address):  # knowing the client reason - log in or sign up

    reason = connection.recv(1024)
    print reason
    if reason == 'log in':
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.log_in, args=(connection, address,))
        t.start()
    elif reason == 'sign up':
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.sign_up, args=(connection, address,))
        t.start()

def log_in(self, connection, address):  # log in

    button = connection.recv(1024)
    print button
    if button == 'Return':
        self.first_stage(connection, address)
    else:
        account_name = connection.recv(1024)
        print 'user', account_name
        account_password = connection.recv(1024)

        print 'pass', account_password
        print self.clients_dict
        if account_name in self.clients_dict:
            print 'ok1'
            if self.clients_dict[account_name][0] == account_password:
                print'ok2'
                connection.send('True')
                self.clients_dict[account_name][1] = address
                self.clients_dict[account_name][3] = 'connected'
                self.clients += 1
                self.chat_stage(connection, address, account_name)
            else:
                connection.send('Wrong password')
                self.log_in(connection, address)
        else:
            connection.send('No User')
            self.log_in(connection, address)

def sign_up(self, connection, address):  # sign up

    button = connection.recv(1024)  # return or sign up
    print button  # return or sign up
    if button == 'return':
        self.first_stage(connection, address)
    elif button == 'mail error':
        self.first_stage(connection, address)
    else:
        user_name = connection.recv(1024)
        print 'user', user_name
        user_password = connection.recv(1024)
        print 'pass', user_password
        user_mail = connection.recv(1024)
        print 'mail', user_mail
        if user_name in self.clients_dict:  # user name exists
            connection.send('user name is taken')
            self.sign_up(connection, address)
        else:
            try:  # checks if mail address is valid
                    fromaddr = "davidovici1999@gmail.com"
                    subject = user_name + " nice to meet you!"
                    toaddr = user_mail
                    msg = MIMEMultipart()
                    msg['From'] = fromaddr
                    msg['To'] = toaddr
                    code = randint(100, 999)
                    msg['Subject'] = subject
                    body = "hello this is your entry code: " + str(code)
                    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
                    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                    server.starttls()
                    server.login(fromaddr, "17074444")
                    text = msg.as_string()
                    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
                    server.quit()
                    connection.send("sent to mail")
                    code_try = connection.recv(1024)  # check if code is equal
                    if code_try == str(code):  # sign innnnn
                        self.clients_dict[user_name] = [user_password, address, connection, 'connected', user_mail]
                        connection.send('connected')
                        print 'ok', self.clients_dict
                        data = connection.recv(1024)
                        print data  # log in
                        self.log_in(connection, address)
                    else:  # code isn't equal
                        print 'wronggg'
                        connection.send("code isn't equal")
                        data = connection.recv(1024)  # sign up
                        print data
                        self.sign_up(connection, address)
            except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:  # fix - isnt working
                connection.send("mail isn't valid")
                data = connection.recv(1024)  # sign up
                self.sign_up(connection, address)

def chat_stage(self, connection, address, account_name):  # the chat itself stage

    print 'success'
    dat = connection.recv(1024)
    print "what? " + dat
    if dat == 'Private':
        self.start_conversation(account_name)
    elif dat == '2':
        list = self.clients_dict[account_name][2].recv(1024).split("#$")
        print "listtttt"
        dictionary = self.clients_dict
        list.append(account_name)
        print "listtttt", list
        g = GroupChat(list, dictionary)
        print 'created a GC object'
        g.run()
        print "got g running"
    elif dat == 'broad':
        print 'broad cast'
        list = self.clients_dict[account_name][2].recv(1024).split("#$")
        print list
        print 'hello'
        dictionary = self.clients_dict
        print "list", list
        b = BroadCast(list, dictionary, account_name)
        print 'created a BC object'
        b.run()
        print "got b running"

def start_conversation(self, account_name):  # 4

    chatter_name = self.clients_dict[account_name][2].recv(1024)
    print chatter_name
    print self.clients_dict
    if chatter_name in self.clients_dict:
        message = "Private From " + account_name
        # self.clients_dict[chatter_name][2].send(message)
        p = PrivateChat(self.clients_dict[account_name][2], self.clients_dict[chatter_name][2])
        p.run()
    else:
        logging.debug("there is no such user")


class PrivateChat(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, connection1, connection2):

    super(PrivateChat, self).__init__()  # 0

    self.connection1 = connection1
    self.connection2 = connection2

def con1_receive(self):

    while True:
        data = decryption(self.connection2.recv(1024))
        self.connection1.send(encryption(data))

def con2_receive(self):

    while True:
        data = decryption(self.connection1.recv(1024))
        self.connection2.send(encryption(data))

def run(self):  # 1

    t = threading.Thread(target=self.con1_receive)
    tt = threading.Thread(target=self.con2_receive)
    while True:
        logging.debug("hello")
        t.start()
        tt.start()
        t.join()
        tt.join()
        logging.debug("bye bye")


class GroupChat():

def __init__(self, list, dictionary):

    self.chatters_list = list
    self.cli_dic = dictionary
    self.conn_list = []
    print list
    for name in self.chatters_list:
        print "in 1st loop in init g"
        if name in self.cli_dic:
            print "in 2nd loop in init g"
            self.conn_list.append(self.cli_dic[name][2])
            print self.conn_list
            print self.cli_dic[name][2]
    print "in g after organizing"

def communication(self, connection):

    print "in communication"
    data = decryption(connection.recv(1024))
    print data
    logging.debug("received a message")
    for con in self.conn_list:
        con.send(encryption(data))

def run(self):

    print "in run in g"  # isn't go in the for loop
    print self.conn_list
    while True:
        for con in self.conn_list:
            print "start a thread"
            threading.Thread(target=self.communication, args=(con,)).start()


class BroadCast():

def __init__(self, list, dictionary, sender):

    self.receivers = list
    self.cli_dic = dictionary
    self.sender = sender
    self.conn_list = []
    self.sender_connection = self.cli_dic[sender][2]
    print list
    for name in self.receivers:
        if name in self.cli_dic:
            print "in 2nd loop in init b"
            self.conn_list.append(self.cli_dic[name][2])
            print self.conn_list
            print self.cli_dic[name][2]

def message(self):

    while True:
        message = self.sender_connection.recv(1024)
        for con in self.conn_list:
            con.send(message)

def run(self):

    threading.Thread(target=self.message).start()


def main():

s = Server(HOST, PORT)
t = threading.Thread(target=s.search_for_connections)
t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

The clients code:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s',)
# logging.debug
REGULAR_EXPRESSION = '\.*\w+\.*\w*@\w+\.\w+\.*\w*'


class Client(object):

def __init__(self, ip, port):  # defining the client

    self.ip = ip
    self.port = port
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.connect((self.ip, self.port))
    self.message = ''
    self.open()

def open(self):  # open the first window with two options - log in or sign up

    self.root = Tk()
    self.label3 = Label(self.root, text="Welcome to the greatest chat!", font="Helvetica 8 bold italic")
    self.button1 = Button(self.root, text="log in", command=self.log_in)
    self.button2 = Button(self.root, text="sign up", command=self.sign_up)
    self.label3.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.05)
    self.button1.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.3, width=170, height=50)
    self.button2.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.6, width=170, height=50)
    self.root.mainloop()

def sign_up(self):  # sign up

    self.sock.send("sign up")
    self.root.destroy()
    self.root = Tk()
    self.label3 = Label(self.root, text="Welcome to the greatest chat!", font="Helvetica 8 bold italic")
    self.label1 = Label(self.root, text="name")
    self.label2 = Label(self.root, text="password")
    self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
    self.entry2 = Entry(self.root, show="*")
    self.button = Button(self.root, text="sign up", width=10, bg='red', height=2, command=self.return_sign)
    self.label4 = Label(self.root, text="what is your email?")
    self.entry3 = Entry(self.root)
    self.label3.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.05)
    self.label1.place(relx=0, rely=0.2)
    self.label2.place(relx=0, rely=0.3)
    self.entry1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2)
    self.entry2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3)
    self.button.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.75)
    self.label4.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.45)
    self.entry3.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.6, width=180)
    self.c = Button(self.root, text="Return", command=self.return_button, bg='brown')
    self.c.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.9)
    self.root.geometry("200x350+50+50")
    self.root.mainloop()

def return_sign(self):  # sends the server the details

    self.name = self.entry1.get()
    self.password = self.entry2.get()
    self.mail = self.entry3.get()
    if re.match(REGULAR_EXPRESSION, self.mail) is not None:
        self.sock.send('sign up')
        self.root.destroy()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.sock.send(self.name)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.sock.send(self.password)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.sock.send(self.mail)
        situation = self.sock.recv(1024)  # situation
        if situation == 'sent to mail':  # checks the code
            self.root = Tk()
            self.label = Label(self.root, text='we sent a code to your mail please copy it')
            self.entry9 = Entry(self.root)
            self.button = Button(self.root, text='ok', command=self.check_code)
            self.label.pack()
            self.button.pack()
            self.entry9.pack()
            self.root.mainloop()
        elif situation == 'user name is taken':  # user name is taken
            self.root.destroy()
            self.name_taken(situation)
    else:  # opens a window of error
        self.sock.send('mail error')
        self.root.destroy()
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label = Label(self.root, text='the mail address is not valid')
        self.button = Button(self.root, text='try again', command=self.sign_up)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

def check_code(self):

    code = self.entry9.get()
    self.root.destroy()
    self.sock.send(code)
    answer = self.sock.recv(1024)
    if answer == 'connected':
        print 'connected successfully'  # connected
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label = Label(self.root, text='connected successfully')
        self.button = Button(self.root, text='ok', command=self.log_in)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
    elif answer == "code isn't equal":
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label = Label(self.root, text='code is incorrect')
        self.button = Button(self.root, text='try again', command=self.sign_up)
        self.label.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

def name_taken(self, message):  # opens a window of error

    self.root = Tk()
    self.label = Label(self.root, text=message)
    self.button = Button(self.root, text='try again', command=self.sign_up)
    self.label.pack()
    self.button.pack()
    self.root.mainloop()

def log_in(self):  # log in

    self.sock.send("log in")
    self.root.destroy()
    self.root = Tk()
    self.label1 = Label(self.root, text="name")
    self.label2 = Label(self.root, text="password")
    self.entry1 = Entry(self.root, bd=3)
    self.entry2 = Entry(self.root, show="*", bd=3)
    self.button = Button(self.root, text="log in", command=self.return_namepass, bg='red')
    self.label3 = Label(self.root, text="Welcome to the greatest chat!", font="Helvetica 8 bold italic")
    self.label1.place(relx=0, rely=0.2)
    self.label2.place(relx=0, rely=0.3)
    self.label3.place(relx=0.08, rely=0.05)
    self.entry1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2)
    self.entry2.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3)
    self.button.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.5, width=100, height=50)
    self.c = Button(self.root, text="Return", command=self.return_button, bg='brown')
    self.c.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8)
    self.root.mainloop()

def return_button(self):  # returns to the first window

    self.sock.send("Return")
    self.root.destroy()
    self.open()

def return_namepass(self):  # sends the server the details

    self.sock.send('log innnn')
    self.user_name = self.entry1.get()
    self.user_password = self.entry2.get()
    self.root.destroy()
    print self.user_name
    print self.user_password
    self.sock.send(self.user_name)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    self.sock.send(self.user_password)
    ok = self.sock.recv(1024)
    print ok
    if ok == 'True':
        self.ok = True
    elif ok == 'No User':
        self.ok = False
        self.message = 'No such user'
    elif ok == 'Wrong password':
        self.ok = False
        self.message = 'Wrong password'
    else:
        print 'there is a problem please check it out'
    if not self.ok:
        self.incorrect()
    print "connected successfully"
    self.decide_what()

def decide_what(self):

    self.window = Tk()
    self.window.title("options")
    self.window.geometry("600x250")
    self.window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # cant resize
    self.label = Label(self.window, text='CHOOSE YOUR FIRST OPTION!', font=30)
    self.label.place(x=200, y=13)
    self.button1 = Button(self.window, text='PrivateChat', font=30, command=self.private)
    self.button1.place(x=1, y=50, width=200, height=199)
    self.button2 = Button(self.window, text='GroupChat', font=30, command=self.group)
    self.button2.place(x=201, y=50, width=199, height=199)
    self.button3 = Button(self.window, text='BroadCast', font=30, command=self.broadcast)
    self.button3.place(x=400, y=50, width=200, height=199)
    self.button4 = Button(self.window, text='SignOut', font=30, command=self.window.destroy)
    self.button4.place(x=500, y=10)
    self.window.mainloop()

def broadcast(self):

    self.window.destroy()
    self.b = BroadCast(self.user_name, self.sock)

def group(self):

    self.sock.send('2')
    x = raw_input("add a chatter: ")
    lis = []
    while x != 'STOP':
        lis.append(x)
        x = raw_input("add a chatter: ")
    self.sock.send('#$'.join(lis))

def private(self):

    self.window.destroy()
    self.p = PrivateChat(self.user_name, self.sock)

def incorrect(self):

    self.root = Tk()
    self.label = Label(self.root, text=self.message)
    self.button = Button(self.root, text='try again', command=self.try_again)
    self.label.pack()
    self.button.pack()
    self.root.mainloop()

def try_again(self):

    self.log_in()

def send_message(self):  # a function that responsible to send a message to the server
    while True:
        self.sock.send(encryption(raw_input()))

def receiving_message(self):  # a function that responsible to receive a message from the server

    while True:
        data = self.sock.recv(1024)
        data = decryption(data)
        if data[:13] == "BroadCastZone":
            self.window = Tk()
            self.window.title("BroadCastZone")
            self.label = Label(self.window, text=data)
            self.label.pack()
            self.button = Button(self.window, text="ok", command=self.window.destroy)
            self.button.pack()
            self.window.mainloop()
            print data
        elif data[:7] == "Private":
            pass
        else:
            print data


class PrivateChat():

def __init__(self, sender, connection):

    self.receiver = '?'
    self.sender = sender
    self.connection = connection
    self.connection.send("Private")
    self.who_receives()

def who_receives(self):

    self.Private_window = Tk()
    self.Private_window.title('Private')
    self.Private_window.geometry("250x300")
    self.Private_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # cant resize

    # Create a Chat window
    self.chat_log = Text(self.Private_window, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
    # self.chat_log.config(state=DISABLED) ???
    self.chat_log.place(x=6, y=6, height=200, width=220)
    # Bind a self.scrollbar to the Chat window
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.Private_window, command=self.chat_log.yview, cursor="star")
    self.chat_log['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set
    self.scrollbar.place(x=230, y=6, height=200)
    # Create the Button to send message
    self.send_button = Button(self.Private_window, text="Send", width="6", height='50',
                bd=0, bg="red", activebackground="pink",
                command=self.send_receiver)
    self.send_button.place(x=200, y=240, height=50)
    self.entry_box = Text(self.Private_window, bd=0, bg="white", width="20", height="5", font="Arial")
    self.entry_box.bind("<Return>", self.disable_entry)
    self.entry_box.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.press_action)
    self.entry_box.place(x=6, y=240, height=50, width=190)
    self.label1 = Label(self.Private_window, text="with whom do you want to talk ? ")
    self.label1.place(x=6, y=212)
    self.Private_window.mainloop()

def disable_entry(self, event):

    self.entry_box.config(state=DISABLED)

def press_action(self, event):

    self.entry_box.config(state=NORMAL)

def send_receiver(self):

    receiver = self.entry_box.get('0.0', END)
    self.connection.send(receiver.strip())
    self.Private_window.destroy()
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.conversation)
    t.start()

def receive_private_message(self):

    while True:
        message = self.connection.receive(1024)
        print message

def conversation(self):

    self.private_chat_window = Tk()
    self.private_chat_window.title('BroadCast')
    self.private_chat_window.geometry("250x300")
    self.private_chat_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # cant resize
    self.chat_log = Text(self.private_chat_window, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
    self.chat_log.place(x=6, y=6, height=200, width=220)
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.private_chat_window, command=self.chat_log.yview, cursor="star")
    self.chat_log['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set
    self.scrollbar.place(x=230, y=6, height=200)
    self.send_button = Button(self.private_chat_window, text="Send", width="6", height='50',
                bd=0, bg="red", activebackground="pink",
                command=self.click_action)
    self.send_button.place(x=200, y=240, height=50)
    self.entry_box = Text(self.private_chat_window, bd=0, bg="white", width="20", height="5", font="Arial")
    self.entry_box.bind("<Return>", self.disable_entry)
    self.entry_box.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.press_action)
    self.entry_box.place(x=6, y=240, height=50, width=190)
    self.label1 = Label(self.private_chat_window, text="send all the users, at the end - STOP")
    self.label1.place(x=6, y=212)
    self.private_chat_window.mainloop()

def click_action(self):

    entry_text = self.entry_box.get("0.0", END)  # get the message
    self.chat_log.insert(END, entry_text)
    self.entry_box.delete("0.0", END)  # clear the entry
    self.chat_log.yview(END)  # Scroll to the bottom of chat windows

def disable_entry(self, event):

    self.entry_box.config(state=DISABLED)

def press_action(self, event):

    self.entry_box.config(state=NORMAL)


class BroadCast():

def __init__(self, sender, connection):

    self.broad_lis = []
    self.sender = sender
    self.connection = connection
    self.start_broad_cast()
    self.send_broad()

def start_broad_cast(self):

    self.connection.send('broad')
    self.broad_window = Tk()
    self.broad_window.title('BroadCast')
    self.broad_window.geometry("250x300")
    self.broad_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # cant resize
    self.chat_log = Text(self.broad_window, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
    self.chat_log.place(x=6, y=6, height=200, width=220)
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.broad_window, command=self.chat_log.yview, cursor="star")
    self.chat_log['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set
    self.scrollbar.place(x=230, y=6, height=200)
    self.send_button = Button(self.broad_window, text="Send", width="6", height='50',
                bd=0, bg="red", activebackground="pink",
                command=self.click_action)
    self.send_button.place(x=200, y=240, height=50)
    self.entry_box = Text(self.broad_window, bd=0, bg="white", width="20", height="5", font="Arial")
    self.entry_box.bind("<Return>", self.disable_entry)
    self.entry_box.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.press_action)
    self.entry_box.place(x=6, y=240, height=50, width=190)
    self.label1 = Label(self.broad_window, text="send all the users, at the end - STOP")
    self.label1.place(x=6, y=212)
    self.broad_window.mainloop()

def click_action(self):

    entry_text = self.entry_box.get('0.0', END)  # get the message
    self.chat_log.insert(END, entry_text)
    self.entry_box.delete("0.0", END)  # clear the entry
    self.chat_log.yview(END)  # Scroll to the bottom of chat windows
    entry_text = str(entry_text.strip())
    if entry_text != 'STOP':
        print entry_text
        self.broad_lis.append(entry_text)
        print self.broad_lis
    elif str(entry_text) == 'STOP':
        print entry_text
        print "#$".join(self.broad_lis)
        self.connection.send("#$".join(self.broad_lis))
        print 'sent list'
        self.broad_window.destroy()

def disable_entry(self, event):

    self.entry_box.config(state=DISABLED)

def press_action(self, event):

    self.entry_box.config(state=NORMAL)

def send_broad(self):  # a function that responsible to send a message to the server

    self.broad_window = Tk()
    self.broad_window.title('chat box')
    self.broad_window.geometry("700x850")
    self.broad_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)  # cant resize
    self.chat_log = Text(self.broad_window, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
    self.chat_log.place(x=6, y=6, height=730, width=670)
    self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.broad_window, command=self.chat_log.yview, cursor="star")
    self.chat_log['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set
    self.scrollbar.place(x=680, y=6, height=730)
    self.send_button = Button(self.broad_window, font=30, text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                bd=0, bg="red", activebackground="pink",
                command=self.send_message)
    self.send_button.place(x=6, y=750, height=90)
    self.chat_options1 = Button(self.broad_window, text='button1', width='6')
    self.chat_options1.place(x=450, y=750, height=45)
    self.chat_options2 = Button(self.broad_window, text='button2', width='6')
    self.chat_options2.place(x=450, y=800, height=45)
    self.chat_options3 = Button(self.broad_window, text='button3', width='6')
    self.chat_options3.place(x=520, y=800, height=45)
    self.chat_options4 = Button(self.broad_window, text='button4', width='6')
    self.chat_options4.place(x=520, y=750, height=45)
    self.chat_out = Button(self.broad_window, text='sign out', width=11, height=5, command=self.broad_window.destroy)
    self.chat_out.place(x=590, y=755)
    self.entry_box = Text(self.broad_window, bd=0, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
    self.entry_box.bind("<Return>", self.disable_entry)
    self.entry_box.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", self.press_action)
    self.entry_box.place(x=128, y=750, height=90, width=300)
    self.broad_window.mainloop()

def send_message(self):

    message = self.entry_box.get('0.0', END)
    self.chat_log.insert(END, message)
    self.entry_box.delete("0.0", END)  # clear the entry
    self.chat_log.yview(END)  # Scroll to the bottom of chat windows
    message = str(message.strip())
    self.connection.send(encryption(padding("BroadCastZone from " + self.sender + ": " + message)))


def main():

c = Client('127.0.0.1', 555)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=c.send_message) 
t1.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target=c.receiving_message)  
t2.start()
```

Comment: That's far too much code to go into details, but I notice you use blocking sockets calls. Consider writing the guts of the chat protocol in background threads. You could use a messaging protocol like zeromq and have a unique identifier per conversation or perhaps use non-blocking sockets with `select` or python's asyncore (see their [chat example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asynchat.html#module-asynchat)).

Comment: You should define some kind of a protocol, so when a user sends a message that should only be visible by one other user (or more), to add the target user name(s) at the beginning (+some tags). Then the server should have a  mapping between user/client names and client sockets, so when such a message arrives, it unpacks it gets the user and send the original message on the socket associated with the user. Or the possibility that the client can connect to another client (so every client should also be a server) and the main server only does client management and "sendall" type messages handling.

Comment: well, if ill do that there will be a problem because the server wont be able to send the message through the right argument